# Crash on ImageLoaderMachO on app loading on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, exc-bad-access

I'm getting a crash when the app load from the debugger ( `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` ), on this line (asm):

```
__dyld__ZN16ImageLoaderMachO12bindLocationERKN11ImageLoader11LinkContextEmmPKS0_hPKclS7_+320>
```

I understand it has something with **image loader**, but I can't figure what.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some more information? e.g. the entire stack trace where it crashes?

Comment: You've got to give us more information. Where is is crashing on your code? In appDidFinishLaunching? Where?

Look for a little slider at the bottom left of the Debugger pane on the lower left. This shows the granularity of the debug output. Drag it all the way to the right. That might you help see where the crash is happening more clearly.

Also, you REALLY want to set a few breakpoints to islolate the crash.

Is it happening before or after appDidFinishLaunching? Is it happening in a storyboard?

You need to know this information so that you can give it to us so that we can help you.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**----Found your Solution-----**

Add dylib1.o from "Link Binary Section " of Build Phases in XCode--- it will solve the error...

Comment: I'm having this same issue, and it didn't work for me. I'm running a new app project, created with Xcode 6. I deleted the storyboard and the "Main Interface", but the didFinishLaunching in the app delegate is not even called!

Answer (score 0):

Add Foundation.framework and UIKit.framework from link binary option.
Then run again. It fixed my issue.